# If on a local branch, how should I push that repo to remote from local repo that already exists?

Tags: git, github, local, remote-access

I am pretty new to programing/git and am trying to learn best practice.
If I have a repo I created on my computer, what is the best way to make that a repo on github.

I have been creating on github for the most part and would like to know what the practice would be if I wanted/needed to do it in reverse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/) first. To avoid confusion create it with the same name you already have to your repository.

Change the current working directory

```
cd project_folder
```

Assuming you have initialized your repository and committed some files using:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
```

Copy the newly created repository URL and add remote using this command:

```
git remote add origin remote_repository_URL
```

push to remote repository

```
git push origin master 
# master here is your branch
```

Follow [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) link for detailed steps

Answer (score 1):

Remember that before pushing your repository to GitHub you need to commit your changes:

```
git commit -m "My last changes"
```

Then you need to create empty project on [GitHub](https://github.com/) without readme nor gitignore file.

To send your code to github you shall add remote(which is your empty github project) to your local repository:

```
git remote add origin <github project url>
```

At last you should push your state of repository to remote:

```
git push origin master
```